# Optimizing a block copy in ARM assembly

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, arm, micro-optimization

I am trying to optimise a block loop for memory usage and time in which the values in the registers are divided by two and then saturated by5 but the code I have got includes numerous branch instructions, I was wondering if after loading the 8 registers,there was a way to move them into the register all at once to restrict multiple branches or a single instruction that could do them both in the same line?

```
 THUMB
 AREA RESET, CODE, READONLY
 EXPORT  __Vectors
 EXPORT Reset_Handler
__Vectors 
 DCD 0x00180000     ; top of the stack 
  DCD Reset_Handler  ; reset vector - where the program starts

  AREA Task2b_Code, CODE, READONLY
  Reset_Handler
  ENTRY

  num_words EQU (end_source-source)/4  ; number of words to copy

  start 
  LDR r0,=source     ; point to the start of the area of memory to copy from
  LDR r1,=dest       ; point to the start of the area of memory to copy to
  MOV r2,#num_words  ; get the number of words to copy

  ; find out how many blocks of 8 words need to be copied - it is assumed
  ; that it is faster to load 8 data items at a time, rather than load
  ; individually
block
  MOVS r3,r2,LSR #3  ; find the number of blocks of 8 words
  BEQ individ        ; if no blocks to copy, just copy individual words

  ; copy and process blocks of 8 words 
block_loop
  LDMIA r0!,{r5-r12}  ; get 8 words to copy as a block
  MOV r4,r5           ; get first item
  BL data_processing  ; process first item 
  MOV r5,r4           ; keep first item
  MOV r4,r6           ; get second item
  BL data_processing  ; process second item 
  MOV r6,r4           ; keep second item
  MOV r4,r7           ; get third item
  BL data_processing  ; process third item
  MOV r7,r4           ; keep third item  
  MOV r4,r8           ; get fourth item
  BL data_processing  ; process fourth item 
  MOV r8,r4           ; keep fourth item
  MOV r4,r9           ; get fifth item
  BL data_processing  ; process fifth item
  MOV r9,r4           ; keep fifth item  
  MOV r4,r10          ; get sixth item
  BL data_processing  ; process sixth item 
  MOV r10,r4          ; keep sixth item
  MOV r4,r11          ; get seventh item
  BL data_processing  ; process seventh item
  MOV r11,r4          ; keep seventh item 
  MOV r4,r12          ; get eighth item
  BL data_processing  ; process eighth item
  MOV r12,r4          ; keep eighth item  
  STMIA r1!,{r5-r12}  ; copy the 8 words 
  SUBS r3,r3,#1       ; move on to the next block
  BNE block_loop      ; continue until last block reached

  ; there may now be some data items available (fewer than 8)
  ; find out how many of these individual words need to be copied 
individ
  ANDS r3,r2,#7   ; find the number of words that remain to copy individually
  BEQ exit        ; skip individual copying if none remains

  ; copy the excess of words
individ_loop
  LDR r4,[r0],#4      ; get next word to copy
  BL data_processing  ; process the item read
  STR r4,[r1],#4      ; copy the word 
  SUBS r3,r3,#1       ; move on to the next word
  BNE individ_loop    ; continue until the last word reached

  ; languish in an endless loop once all is done
exit    
  B exit

  ; subroutine to scale a value by 0.5 and then saturate values to a maximum of 5 
data_processing
  CMP r4,#10           ; check whether saturation is needed
  BLT divide_by_two    ; if not, just divide by 2
  MOV r4,#5            ; saturate to 5
  BX lr
divide_by_two
  MOV r4,r4,LSR #1     ; perform scaling
  BX lr

  AREA Task2b_ROData, DATA, READONLY
source  ; some data to copy
  DCD 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0,4,6,12,15,13,8,5,4,3,2,1,6,23,11,9,10 
end_source

  AREA Task2b_RWData, DATA, READWRITE
dest  ; copy to this area of memory
  SPACE end_source-source
end_dest
  END
```

Comment: Do care about any particular ARM microarchitectures?  A microcontroller or is this for an app that will run on a range of phones?  In-order vs.  Out-of-order?  Cache enabled? copying from RAM to RAM?  Is NEON available?

Comment: But yeah, this code is obviously bad on any ARM.  `data_processing` should be branchless and inlined.  To save code size you could just use a smaller `LDMIA`; I don't think LDMIA is particularly fast; it is microcoded.  You can use Thumb `.it` for predicates, right?

Comment: As per Peter, move `data_processing` to a macro; a macro can take a registers argument so the registers don't need to move.  Also, you can do `mov rN, rN, LSR #1` and then `it gt; cmp rN,#5; movgt rN,#5`.  rN is a macro parameters.  You may be able to use [`usat`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBEHJF.html) if available or just use a table if the values are range bound, but these things depend on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code

```
area blockCopy, code
 entry
 ldr r0,= 0x40000000
 ldr r1,= 0x40000020
 mov r4,#5

up ldr r3,[r0],#4
 str r3,[r1],#4
 subs r4,r4,#1
 BNE up

stop b stop
 end
```

Comment: Why should people use this?  What makes it efficient on any particular ARM core?  The question is trying to optimize by unrolling loops.  (And is doing some processing on the fly, unlike the title it's not just memcpy.)